Is using “the ones” correct in this sentence?
My school is organizing a dance party and I wanted to announce it on my Instagram story, writing something like this about the tickets

You have my permission to steal [my school’s name] tickets if the ones for your school are already gone.

However, I don’t know if saying “the ones” sounds okay and natural. Would it be better if I wrote

You have my permission to steal [my school’s name] tickets if those for your school are already gone.

What do you think and does the whole thing sound natural?

Why exactly do you think it might sound unnatural?

Tbh, I don’t know! I think I’m just anxious that many people will see that so I’m trying to be extra cautious:)

You could substitute "tickets" for "ones" if you're really concerned. But if you're talking about stealing tickets you're using a casual register, so I wouldn't worry too much about proper grammar, and just write what seems natural to you.

Yes, that's perfect. Welcome to EL&U!

It's fine. The pro-form "one" is a common noun that has the plural form "ones" .
